# eloquent where id in from many to many

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
users
id

roles
id
name

user_roles
user_id
role_id
```

I would like to query all users with specific roles.
e.g. get all users that have the role 'admin'

Answer (score 2):

So, you can use the *whereHas* from Eloquent

```
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'admin');
})->get();
```

See here for reference https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 2):

There is also the option to go at the relationship from the other direction:

```
Role::where('name', 'admin')->firstOrFail()->users;
```

Comment: Is there also a way to do this as part of another query:
e.g. Comment::where('user' ... is user with role admin?

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you know role ID, do this:

```
User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) use($roleId) {
    $q->where('id', $roleId);
})
->get();
```

If you know only name or title of the role, do this:

```
User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) use($roleTitle) {
    $q->where('title', $roleTitle);
})
->get();
```